# store output of last executed command in expect script

Tags: python, shell, expect

I have an expect script which is as below

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set user [lrange $argv 0 0] 
set password [lrange $argv 1 1] 
set ipaddr [lrange $argv 2 2]
set command [lrange $argv 3 3]
set timeout 10
# now connect to remote UNIX box (ipaddr) with given script to execute
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $user@$ipaddr $command
expect "*?assword:*"
# Send password aka $password
send -- "$password\r"
interact
# send blank line (\r) to make sure we get back to gui
#send -- "\r"
```

This expect script is called from a python script which passes the below string to the command variable

"/bin/bash customStart.sh"

$command variable has the above value.

this customStart.sh echos "running" or "not running"  based on conditions.
I want to capture this "running" or "not running" in python script via the expect script.

In short the flow is as follows.

python script--->expect script --->customStart.sh

customStart.sh-------"running" or "not running"-----> expect script ---> python.

Python calls the expect script using subprocess.check_output(). So first I need to bring the "running" or "not running" in expect script which can be then passed to python.

How should I do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you considered using [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)?

Comment: The problem is this script will be deployed on remote server.So I am not sure if it has pexpect.

Comment: See the expect [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect). `send_user` will print output to STDOUT (as opposed to sending to the spawned process), and `log_user` will control whether the expect dialog is sent to STDOUT or not.

Comment: Yes send_user will print output to STDOUT, but is there any command  in expect which should follow send_user , like $? in shell which prints status of last executed command.

Answer (score 0):

> ...but is there any command in expect which should follow send_user ,
>   like $? in shell which prints status of last executed command

There is a global variable "errorCode" that contains the error code from command that failed.
Please see Tcl manual "Debugging and errors":

https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl36.html